# Accessing main() in public static void main(String arg[])

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Can a main() be accessed directly from outside the class in which it is defined?
Like for example:

```
class B
{ 
    main();
}

class A
{
   public static void main(String arg[])
   { int a=10;
     int b=20;

     System.out.println(a+" "+b);
   }

}
```

Comment: Let's assume that the code could actually compile, in order to call `main` from class `B`, you would need an instance of `B`, something like `B b = new B();`, then you can use `b` to call `main`, something like `b.main();`

Comment: You might like to have a closer look at [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and the associated tutorials for more information

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes. I could do that but as main() has a public modifier and is in class A, I thought of if it could only be directly accessed from within the same class or also from outside the class.

Comment: You wouldn't need an instance of class A to call `A.main` because `main` is a `static` method.

Comment: @BIJAY I'm probably misinterpreting the question, you might like to clarify it more

Comment: Yes David. But is it possible for accessing main() in class A directly from outside the class?

Comment: @BIJAY You can sit around and wait for random people on the Internet to contribute, or _you can write some code and try it yourself_.  That should take a few minutes and you will have your answer long before someone here chimes in.

Comment: In your example, @BIJAY, `main()` is a non-public instance method of `B`, and `main(String[])` is a public static method of `A`. Given the similarity of the function names, would you please be more cautious how you speak of them? The name confusion is bad enough if you aren't loose about the method signatures.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes let me clarify. I am not asking to call the main() in class B from class A. But asking if I can directly access class A's main() from class B without creating an instance.

Comment: If a method is public, it can be accessed by any other class. This is covered well in the Java Tutorial, @BIJAY.

Comment: @BIJAY You might try and call main by `A.main(new String[]{})` from the B class.

Comment: Yes, @BIJAY.  Someone has added an answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: If a method is static, it can and should be invoked using its declaring type name, and though legal, not via an instance reference. This is covered well in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Thank you all. I got my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call main method from other class as well because its static.no object reference is require to call static method, but you should call it from other method like below.

```
public class B
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {"a"};
        A.main(s);
    }
}

class A
{
   public static void main(String arg[])
   { int a=10;
     int b=20;

     System.out.println(a+" "+b);
   }

}
```